# XOR of 2 lists elements wise in a simple approach

Tags: xor

I wish to do xor of all elements in 2 lists a=[1,2,3], b=[3,4,5] the result should be [2,5,4,1,6,7,0,7,6] in O(1) or O(N).
Please explain your solution as well as approach.

Comment: Is this an assignement for us?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Assuming you want to XOR all elements in A with all elements in B, in this case, O(N) algorithm will need to run in size of A * Size of B.

**The solution could be like this**

```
   let L equal list 
        For each item in A
         For each item2 in B
         L.add(item Xor item2)
```

This is linear on the combined size of A and B

Comment: but the time complexity will be here is O(n2)

Comment: No, it's linear of the size of B * size of A. In this case, you have two lists You need to XOR each element in A with each element in B. You can't do any better than this.In this case 3*3 = 9 operations. An n^2 algorithm would perform 9^2 operations o,  81